# Modify passed, nested dict/list

Tags: python

I was thinking of writing a function to normalize some data. A simple approach is

```
def normalize(l, aggregate=sum, norm_by=operator.truediv):
    aggregated=aggregate(l)
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i]=norm_by(l[i], aggregated)

l=[1,2,3,4]
normalize(l)
l -> [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

However for nested lists and dicts where I want to normalize over an inner index this doesnt work. I mean I'd like to get

```
l=[[1,100],[2,100],[3,100],[4,100]]
normalize(l, ?? )
l -> [[0.1,100],[0.2,100],[0.3,100],[0.4,100]]
```

Any ideas how I could implement such a normalize function?

Maybe it would be crazy cool to write

```
normalize(l[...][0])
```

Is it possible to make this work?? Or any other ideas?

Also not only lists but also dict could be nested. Hmm...

EDIT:
I just found out that numpy offers such a syntax (for lists however). Anyone know how I would implement the ellipsis trick myself?

Comment: Any important reason to make in-place operations instead of creating new objects? it may be slightly slower, but it pays off on the long run.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think any change to the `normalize()` function is necessary.  To handle the nested lists, you just need to supply the right `aggregate()` and `norm_by()` functions to handle the case.

```
l = [[1, 100], [2, 100], [3, 100], [4, 100]]
def aggregator(l):
    return sum(item[0] for item in l)

def normalizer(item , aggregated):
    # mutating the inner list
    item[0] = operator.truediv(item[0], aggregated)
    return item

normalize(l, aggregate = aggregator, norm_by = normalizer)
# l -> [[0.1, 100], [0.2, 100], [0.3, 100], [0.4, 100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
zip(normalize(zip(*l)[0]), zip(*l)[1])
```

There is one (normally unimportant) side effect: the inner lists are transformed into tuples. This can, however, be corrected with `[list(el) for el in zip(normalize(zip(*l)[0]), zip(*l)[1])]`.

If you have a dict, I suppose it would look like `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`, the values needing normalizing. You could use the above trick by using `l.items()`:

```
dict(zip(normalize(zip(*l.items())[0]), zip(*l.items())[1]))
```

**EDIT:**

You could do something like this:

```
def normalize(l, aggregate=sum, norm_by=operator.truediv, key=None):
    aggregated=aggregate(l)
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if key is not None:
            l[i][key] = norm_by(l[i][key], aggregated)
        else:
            l[i]=norm_by(l[i], aggregated)
```

And call the function with

```
normalize(l, key=0)
```

Comment: I'd maybe prefer a way to extend the normalize function so that it is more comfortable in the long run :) and which doesn't transform too much, as the sequences might be very large. Either the Ellipsis syntax I thought of maybe something like normalize(l, further_access=?? [0])

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating new objects instead of modifying in-place. Assuming that each element in the iterable may be different (if not, you can make it more efficient by selecting the merge function earlier):

```
def normalize(input, index=None, aggregate=sum, norm_by=operator.truediv):
    aggregated = aggregate(input)
    for item in input:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield item[:index] + [norm_by(item[index], aggregated)] + item[index+1:]
        elsif isinstance(item, dict):
            yield dict(d, **{index: norm_by(item[index], aggregated)})
        else:
            yield norm_by(item, aggregated)
```

To be used:

```
normalize([1, 2, 3])
normalize([(1, 2), (3, 4)], 0)
normalize([{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}], "a")
```